# Setting <div> height property in Dart

Tags: css, dart

I'm learning Dart and I'm stuck on changing the height of a `<div>`. Any help appreciated.

```html
<div id="sample_container_id">
    <p id="sample_text_id"></p>
</div>
```

```dart
import 'dart:html';
void main() 
{
  DivElement div = query('#sample_container_id');
  div.style.height = "40000";
}
```

Comment: I think you're just missing your unit. Try setting div.style.height to "1000px" for example.

Comment: thanks it works with "400000px"...I can now move on

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @richthepanda in the comments, you're correctly setting the `height` property of your `div` element with your Dart code, but you're setting it to an invalid [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height) string as far as having the browser do what you want with it.  Adding the intended unit fixes the issue:

```dart
  div.style.height = "40000px";
```